# Переход между вкладками solidworks

Tags: vba

Есть 2 открытые вкладки solidworks 1я -  модель 2я - чертёж.
Нужно с помощью vba переключаться между ними. Как это реализуется? 
Я пытался найти способы решения этой проблемы в интернете, но несколько часов поиска не помогли.